# Tensorflow implementation for a simple logic

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a new in Tensorflow. I want to implement an algorithm in Tensorflow that has a part of simple logic described bellow.

I have a matrix (the size of matrix could be vary from a batch size). I need to replace all values in the matrix with zeros except maximum values in each row.

I want to implement this simple logic in Tensorflow API.

For example:

```
Input:
[[0.50041455 0.41183667 0.37627002]
 [0.57736448 0.90280652 0.70880312]
 [0.50961863 0.94126878 0.86982843]
 [0.30285231 0.6302716  0.76009756]]
Output:
[[0.50041455 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.9028065  0.        ]
 [0.         0.9412688  0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.76009756]]
```

This is mine code. But I don't want to use placeholder for "Y" and run tenserflow 2 times. (I worry about performace in GPU)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

num_classes = 3
batch_size = 4

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes]) #My matrix

values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(X, 1)
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes])

M = X * Y

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    x = np.random.rand(batch_size, num_classes)
    print(x)
    ind = sess.run([indices], feed_dict={X: x})
    y = np.zeros(shape=[batch_size, num_classes], dtype=float)
    for i in range(batch_size):
        y[i, ind[0][i][0]]= 1.0
    m = sess .run(M, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
    print(m)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

Ideally, we hope to mark the position with the largest element in the row with 1 and others with 0. Then we just need to multiply those two matrix element-wise.

To get the position of the large element, we could use `tf.argmax` which help us find the index of the largest element in corresponding axis, and `tf.one_hot` which turn above result into the same shape as the initial input matrix. For detailed behavor of `tf.one_hot`, you may hope to read
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot

The example code is as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

num_classes = 3

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, num_classes))

# Calculate the max element in each row, -1 means the last axis
max_in_row = tf.argmax(inputs, axis=-1)

output = tf.one_hot(max_in_row, num_classes) * inputs

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (
        sess.run(output, feed_dict={
            inputs:
            [[0.50041455, 0.41183667, 0.37627002],
             [0.57736448, 0.90280652, 0.70880312],
             [0.50961863, 0.94126878, 0.86982843],
             [0.30285231, 0.6302716,  0.76009756]]
        })
    )
```

output:

```
[[0.50041455 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.9028065  0.        ]
 [0.         0.9412688  0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.76009756]]
```